# Names are not displaying on the HTML according to JSON Parse

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to display name on the `HTML` page as list items pulling it from `JSON` placeholder It is not displaying on the page.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments');
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
    var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    var str = "<ul>"
    for (var i = 0; i < items.lenght; i++) {
        str = str + "<li>" + items[i].name + "</li>"
    }
    console.log(str);
    str = str + "</ul>"
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = str;
  }
}

request.send();
```

no error display

Comment: You have a typo here `for (var i = 0; i < items.lenght; i++) {`. Change it to `length`

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can see in here is the typo of the array items.

Try to change it to `length`.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments');
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
    var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    var str = "<ul>"
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        str = str + "<li>" + items[i].name + "</li>"
    }
    console.log(str);
    str = str + "</ul>"
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = str;
  }
}

request.send();
```

Comment: @brk this is a question that can be answer. As long as this is not being taken down or something, it is okay to answer. Down voting for what?

Comment: Visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and check point 2

Comment: @brk this is what question should be asked, and not how to answer a question

Answer (score 0):

In your code the major problem was that the typo `items.length` in for loop.

```html
<html> 



<div id="data"></div>




<script>
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments',true);
 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
         var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
         var str = "<ul>"
         for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
             str = str + "<li>" + items[i].name + "</li>"
             
         }
         str = str + "</ul>"
         
         document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = str;
     }
 }
 request.send();
 </script>

 </html>
```

Comment: what are the other problems?

Comment: code is edited in question now there was wrong matching tags and closing tags.